# creating string literal out of array of chars

Tags: arrays, string, string-literals

I want to merge 2 string literals to one

this is my function

```
char* merge(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    char buffer[256]; // <- danger, only storage for 256 characters.
    strncpy(buffer, a, sizeof(buffer));
    strncat(buffer, " ", sizeof(buffer));

    strncat(buffer, b, sizeof(buffer));
    strncat(buffer, "\0", sizeof(buffer));

    char* x = buffer;

    cout <<"ll "<<x<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        buffer[i]='p';
    }
    cout <<"ll "<<x<<endl;
    return x;
}
```

Let's assume a="Michael" and b = John "

output (couts) is:

ll Michael John

ll ppphael John

I made some research and it is like that because x points to array allocated at stack. I want x to be pointing to string literal allocated in read-only section, so my output would be:

ll Michael John

ll Michael John

My question is how to make string literal out of array of chars buffer[256]={M,i,c,h,a,e,l, ,J,o,h,n,\0,0,0,0,0,0,0...,0}

(Don't ask why I'm doing such pointless job, it's for my studies and we are not allowed to use string type nor stl)

Comment: String literals are part of the source code. They're not something you manipulate at runtime.

Comment: This is not C. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: This looks *very much* like C. In modern C++ this is *not* how this would be written.

Comment: In C++ a "literal string" is really a *constant* array of characters with a null-terminator. In C the arrays aren't constant, but only *read-only* (i.e. you still should consider them constant).

Comment: There are also quite a few problems with the code you show, including returning pointers to local variables, and that the string in `buffer` could be missing a terminator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i know I'm returning pointer to local variable thats why i wanted to change it to pointer to string literal if it's possible (seem's not)